# Does a (not-uniformly) convergent sequence of bounded functions converge to a bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Pretty sure the answer is no, but I'd like to see a counter-example of it.

If {fn} is a sequence of bounded functions which converges to f, is f also bounded?

Answer (score 3):

For a somewhat contrived but simple example, define
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
-n & \text{ if }x < -n \\
x & \text{ if }-n \leq x \leq n \\
n & \text{ if }x > n \\
\end{cases}$$
Then each $f_n$ is bounded ($|f_n(x)| \leq n$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$), and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the partial sums of a geometric series

$$ f_1(x) = 1 + x, f_2(x) = 1 + x + x^2, ..., f_n(x) = 1 + x + ... + x^{n-1} + x^n  $$ on $[0,1)$

Each $f_n$ is bounded.  But the limit function is $ f = \frac 1{1-x} $ which has no bounds on the interval.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider the functions $f_n(x)$ with $f_n(x)=x$ if $x\in(-n,n)$ and constant $n$ and $-n$ in $[n,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-n]$  respectively.

Is clear that $f_n(x)\to f(x)=x$ that isn't bounded.

Comment: I guess he wants a sequence that actually converges to a real valued function. In which case one can take $f(x) = \exp(1/(1-x))$ on $[0,1)$ and its Taylor series at $0$.

Comment: I need a sequence of functions that actually converges to a function.

Comment: The Taylor series of $ f(x) = exp(1/(1-x)) $ is not bounded on [0,1).  The numerator of every term goes to infinity when x ->1

Comment: @name65742 OK, I edited